# Proof that the group of non-generators in a multiplicative group with a prime order is a sub-group

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers, cryptography

I'm trying to solve the following problem - Let $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$ be a multiplicative group such that $p=2^k+1$ and is prime. I need to prove that the set of elements that are non-generators in $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_p$ is a sub-group.

My attempt was to take two elements which are non-generators and prove that their product modulu $p$ is also a part of the group of non-generators (In other words, to prove closure and thus convey that it's a sub-group), but I didn't have much success with this.

I'll appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|\mathbb{Z}_p^*| = 2^k$, so that every element has order a power of $2$. Now, if $a$ and $b$ are non-generators, then $|a| = 2^r$ and $|b|=2^s$ for $r, s < k$. But then $|ab| \le \textrm{lcm}(2^r, 2^s) = 2^{\max(r, s)} < 2^k$, so that $ab$ is also a non-generator. (Also, it's clear that $|a| = |a^{-1}|$, so the set of non-generators is also closed under inverses.)

EDIT: Adding discussion of orders.
Letting $d = \textrm{lcm}(2^r, 2^s)$, then we can write $d = 2^rm$ and $d = 2^sn$ for some integers $m, n$, and then
$$(ab)^d = a^db^d = a^{2^rm}b^{2^sn} = \left(a^{2^r}\right)^m\left(a^{2^s}\right)^n = e,$$
so that $|ab| \le d = \textrm{lcm}(2^r, 2^s)$.

Comment: Can you clarify why $|ab|=\text{lcm}(2^r,2^s)$ ?
All the rest is clear . Thanks !

Comment: Is there any proof that I can find for the argument you provided regarding the abelian groups : "if $|a|=r$ and $|b|=s$, then $(ab)^k=e$ when both $a^k=e$ and $b^k=e$, so that $r|k$ and $s|k$." ?

Comment: Please see the addendum to my post. I've deleted my comments to keep things clearer (and correct).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I really appreciate the clear and concise answer .